# How to remove items from a list that doesn't contain keywords from keywords list fast?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YcuCOju1rQhsgBkLMoX7Hknw6xuZ7gzGUYh3GQtT_Us/edit#gid=0), contains sheet `RemoveRecords` and `KeywordsList`

I'd like to remove records that isn't in the `KeywordsList` sheet by searching through the `ArticleLink` column via app scripts.

I'm thinking something along the lines of this as a starting point (this doesn't work):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var rsheet = ss.getSheetByName("RemoveRecords"); 
var ksheet = ss.getSheetByName("KeywordsList"); 
var records = rsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var keywords = ksheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for( var i=records.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    for( var j=0; j<keywords.length; j++){
        if(records[i] && (records[i][1].DoesntContain(keywords[j]))){
            records.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I remove an array that doesn't contain strings from another array?

**Update**
I'm thinking this may be the approach, but it looks like it's looking for exact match:

```js
var filtered = ['ac', 'ab', 'cd', 'g'].filter(
    function(e) {
      return this.indexOf(e) >= 0;
    },
    ['b','a']
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: The question is too broad. How are you reading the spreadsheet values? Are you reading one value at a time of by using something like `getValues()`?

Comment: Edited original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardging the approach included in the question that uses `filter` and `indexOf`, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

> `indexOf()` compares `searchElement` to elements of the Array using [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) (the same method used by the `===` or triple-equals operator).

Instead you could use [RegEx.prototype.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/test). Example:

This example uses Array.prototype.filter, Array.prototype.some and RegEx.prototype.test. Please note that it doesn't make calls to the Spreadsheet Service on the loops, so it should be return the filtered array faster than other solutions that make calls to the Spreadsheet Service on loops.

```
function example(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var rsheet = ss.getSheetByName("RemoveRecords"); 
  var ksheet = ss.getSheetByName("KeywordsList"); 
  var records = rsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var keywords = ksheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var filtered = containsKeyword(records, keywords);
  Logger.log(filtered);

}

function containsKeyword(records, keywords){
  return records.filter(function(row){
    return keywords.some(function(keyword){
      return new RegExp(keyword[0].replace('.','\.')).test(row[1])
    });
  });
}
```

NOTE: The above requires slight chages either to the keyword list or to the regular expression to prevent that partial match be included, i.e. one of the keywords is `al.com` which matchs `https://www.providencejournal.com/opinion/20190810/my-turn-victor-davis-hanson-another-2004-for-democrats`

To remove the records, instead of Logger.log you could clear the sheet and the send the results of `containsKeyword`. This will be faster than calling `deleteRow(pos)` from Class Sheet.

---

Logs resulting of running the above example on my copy the of spreadsheet shared by the OP.

> [19-08-11 17:03:14:932 CDT] [[My Turn: Victor Davis Hanson: Another 2004 for Democrats?, https://www.providencejournal.com/opinion/20190810/my-turn-victor-davis-hanson-another-2004-for-democrats, Sat Aug 10 23:22:21 GMT-05:00 2019, Something similar is shaping up for the Democrats in 2020. ... Many of the Democratic contenders support Medicare for all, reparations for slavery, the ..., MedicareForAll], [Biden, Sanders Both Trounce Trump in Head-to-Head Matchups, New Poll Finds, https://www.newsweek.com/biden-sanders-poll-trump-2020-election-1453658, Sat Aug 10 23:00:00 GMT-05:00 2019, Issues like abortion, LGBTQ rights and treatment of migrants have culled some otherwise-conservative Catholics to the Democratic tent. Biden and ..., LgbtqRights], [San Francisco saw 150 percent spike in fentanyl-related deaths last year, report says, https://www.foxnews.com/health/san-francisco-sees-dramatic-rise-in-fentanyl-related-deaths, Sat Aug 10 23:00:00 GMT-05:00 2019, In 2010, six deaths were attributed to the drug, which killed 22 people in 2016. ... TRUMP DRUG CZAR TOUTS PROGRESS AGAINST OPIOID CRISIS ..., OpioidCrisis]]

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution.  This is a real weakness of mine and I enjoy learning more about these types of array methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Keeping Records using TextFinder in a loop**

```
function keepRecords() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rsh=ss.getSheetByName('RemoveRecords');
  var rrg=rsh.getRange(2,1,rsh.getLastRow()-1,rsh.getLastColumn());
  var lsh=ss.getSheetByName('KeywordsList');
  var lrg=lsh.getRange(2,1,lsh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  var lvA=lrg.getValues();
  var kwlA=lvA.map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var kA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<kwlA.length;i++) {  
    if(kwlA[i]) {
      var fA=rrg.createTextFinder(kwlA[i]).findAll();
      if(fA.length) {
        for(var j=0;j<fA.length;j++) {
          kA.push(rsh.getRange(fA[j].getRow(),1,1,rsh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]);
          //Logger.log('Pushed: Row[%s] because it contained kwlA[%s]=%s',fA[j].getRow(),i,kwlA[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  rrg.clearContent();
  rsh.getRange(2,1,kA.length,kA[0].length).setValues(kA);
}
```

[TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: This deletes records that matches the `KeywordsList` sheet, I'd like to keep the records that matches.

Comment: Now it keeps them